# can two instances of same cocoa app be launched with different bundle id?

Tags: cocoa, bundle, identifier

can two instances of same cocoa app be launched with different bundle ids ?

I want each instance of my app to have different preferences plist in /Library/Preferences/

Comment: If I cannot change bundle identifier, can I pass the location of where my preferences have to end up when launching my app instance ?.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as critiqued, ill be more clear:

#### NO

no, you cant switch an apps identifier on the fly.
they'd have to be two apps.

Comment: note: I dont mention that it MIGHT be possible to edit the info.plist on the fly as it is not defined at all and will very likely cause problems

Comment: also that'd break code signing if you care about that

Comment: it does.. it is a NO! he may not like the answer but it IS an answer

Comment: If I cannot change bundle identifier, can I pass the location of where my preferences have to end up when launching my app instance ?. For example myapp.app instance1 preferences are at /Library/preferences/mypref1.plist and myapp.app instance2 preferences are at /Library/preferences/mypref2.plist.

Comment: if you swizzle the user defaults it might work... there is no 'standard' mechanism :(

Comment: You're right, in hindsight I reviewed this incorrectly. My apologies.